# How do I query and display something for a specific date range with Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to build a small events calendar for a weekly duration. I have the current week starting Monday and ending Sunday

Here is my model for `Event`:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    start = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    end = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my view that displays the date in this format (Oct 21, Oct 22, Oct 23, Oct 24, Oct 25, Oct 26, Oct 27)

```
def events(request, template_name):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    weekday = today.weekday()
    start_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=weekday)
    start_of_week = today - start_delta
    week_dates = []
    for i in range(7):
        week_dates.append(start_of_week + datetime.timedelta(days=i))
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'week_dates': week_dates,
    })
```

My question is, how do I display/attach the event on the specific day during that week? For example, let's say the user chose the `start` date to be Oct 22 and the `end` date to be Oct 26, how do I query and display that under the respective date?

Here is my simple template code for now, this will need to change for styling but for the sake of this question here it is in it's simplest form:

```
    <div id="events">
        {% for d in week_dates %}
            {% for event in events %}
                {{ event.title}}
            {% endfor %}
            {{ d }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: I am not quite sure of what you are asking. But do you want the events to be queried in a date range ?

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi well, I mean I want to get the events from "start" as seen in my models and "end" also seen in my models and group them in the current week output as seen in my code i.e: [Oct 21 - Coffee and Coloring Event] [Oct 22 - Yoga Event] [Oct 23 - Coffee and Coloring Event (day 2)] [Oct 24 - Math]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After querying your events and making their end datetimes equal to start of the day, you can check if enddate is less than the current day in for loop. if I understand what you mean, for example

```
<div id="events">
    {% for d in week_dates %}
        {% for event in events %}
            {% if event.end < d %}
            {{ event.title}}
            {%endif%}

        {% endfor %}
        {{ d }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is that you want to display a calender of events.

I would do something like this in my views:

```
 start_week  = date_a - timedelta(days = date_a.weekday())
 end_week    = date_b + timedelta(days = (7-date_b.weekday()))
 events = Event.objects.filter(Q(start_date__range=[start_week,end_week]) | end_date__range=[start_week, end__week])

event_map = {}

for i in range(7):
    event_map[(start_week + datetime.timedelta(days=i))] = []

for event in events:

    if event.end_date in event_map.keys() and event.start_date not in event_map.keys():
        day_count = (event.end_date - start_week).days
        for i in range(day_count):  
            event_map[event.end_date - timedelta(days=i)].append(event)

    if event.start_date in event_map.keys() and event.end_date not in event_map.keys():
        day_count = (end_week - event.start_date).days
        for i in range(day_count):
            event_map[event.start_date + timedelta(days=i)].append(event)

    else:
        day_count = event.end_date - event.start_date:
        for i in range(day_count):
            event_map[event.start_date+timedelta(days=i)].append(event)
```

Now you can use event_map in your template as:

```
{% for key,value in event_map.items %}
{{key}} -
 {% for i in value %}
  {{i}}
{%endfor%}
 <br>
{% endfor %}
```

I haven't tried this in a project, but logic seems fine to me. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Interesting, this appears to be a solution that I am looking for except whats date_a and date_b?

Comment: date_a and date_b are selected dates for which you want the events.

Actually this logic will fail if end_date for the event in events is outside the range of week. But I hope you get the idea. I will update the answer

Comment: Just updated. I know its not very pythonic (I am repeating a lot of code here), but this should work

Answer (score -1):

Just put it in a query separated with a comma.  You can use full dates, day, month etc...

```
Sample.objects.filter(date__year='2011', date__year='2013')
```

Comment: How can this be grouped with the dates as listed above?